# CSS: Why does removing border drastically affect position of div container?

Tags: css, position, border

I have the following simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#page {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: green;
}
#allcontent {
    position: static;
    top: 225px;
    margin: 225px auto 0px auto;
    width: 850px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#content {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="allcontent">
        <div id="content">
            <p>This is content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks exactly like I want it to look like, but if I remove the border from #page it totally screws up the layout.  I can't figure out why.  I know, I could have a transparent border as a workaround, but it seems odd...

Comment: Using a fiddle to demonstrate your problem would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `margin:225px auto 0px auto` in your `<div id="allcontent">` that pushes the whole content down.

Instead of using `margin`, use `position:absolute/relative` to position your element in your `<div id="page">`.

Comment: Thanks.  I played with it for hours and couldn't figure it out.  Amazing how simple the solution was.  I did not know about the margins collapsing (as pointed out in the link Stefan posted), so I suspect it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The margin for `#allcontent` is pushing it down. 
http://jsfiddle.net/2QjYG/